# Is java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.countDown() atomic?

Tags: java, concurrency

I need reassurance that `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.countDown()` is atomic.

I'm calling `countDown` in `finally` blocks so I'm confident that I'm using it correctly. Occasionally though I see one or two outstanding latches despite my thinking there should be none.

(I haven't managed to verify by checking the Java source code.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need reassurance that java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.countDown() is atomic.

I reassure you, it most definitely is atomic. It would be a critical bug if it was not. I expect you will find your code problem if you debug your code.

> (I haven't managed to verify by checking the Java source code.)

Here's the code trace:

```
public void countDown() {
    sync.releaseShared(1);
}
```

Default implementation of `sync` is:

```
    public boolean tryReleaseShared(int releases) {
        // Decrement count; signal when transition to zero
        for (;;) {
            int c = getState();
            if (c == 0)
                return false;
            int nextc = c-1;
            if (compareAndSetState(c, nextc))
                return nextc == 0;
        }
    }
```

`compareAndSetState` calls which uses the same `Unsafe` class that backs the `AtomicInteger` and many other classes.

```
return unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, expect, update);
```

If it was broken then a large portion of the `java.util.concurrent` are broken.

Comment: Many thanks; I trust you and great to have that one covered off +1 and accept once I can.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's a data structure in `java.util.concurrent` is a dead giveaway, but the [Java code](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch-source.html) uses an [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) which helps to implement atomic operations, and the implementation is pretty straightforward once you read up on the queued synchronizer's API. It's definitely atomic :-)